# android: showing 156 images using gridview inside viewpager

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I would like to show 156 thumbails using Viewpager of 18 pages, with each page having 9 thumbnails. I have implemented as follows:

### Index_gridview class:

```
public void init() 
{  
    PageCount = (int) Math.ceil(mThumbIds.length / PAGE_SIZE);  
    mLists = new ArrayList<GridView>();  

    for (int i = 0; i < PageCount; i++) 
    {  
        GridView gv = new GridView(this);  
        gv.setAdapter(new MyGridViewAdapter(this, mStrs, mThumbIds, i, icon_dimension));  
        gv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  
        gv.setClickable(true);  
        gv.setFocusable(true);  
        gv.setNumColumns(NUMOFCOLUMN);  
        gv.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        gv.setHorizontalSpacing(gridview_horizontal_padding);
        gv.setVerticalSpacing(gridview_vertical_padding);
        mLists.add(gv);  
    }         
    page_number.setText("1/"+PageCount);
}
```

### GridViewAdapter class:

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{   
    private Animation zoom     = null;
    // view
    int icon_width, icon_height;
    Typeface tf;
    private Context mContext;  
    private List<String> mLists;  
    public static final int PAGE_SIZE = 9; // showing how many items in 1 page  

    public MyGridViewAdapter(Context pContext, String[] pStrs, Integer[] image_ref, int page, int width) 
    {  
        this.mContext = pContext;  
        mLists = new ArrayList<String>();  
        int i = page * PAGE_SIZE;  
        int end = i + PAGE_SIZE;  
        while ((i < image_ref.length) && (i < end)) 
        {  
            mLists.add(pStrs[i]); 
            i++;  
        }  

        icon_width = width;
        icon_height = icon_width;

        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"fonts/HomegirlKiddo.ttf");   
    }  

    @Override  
    public int getCount() 
    {           
        return mLists.size();  
    }  
    @Override  
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {           
        return mLists.get(position);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {     
        return position;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menugrid, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageicon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        final int myNum = Integer.parseInt(mLists.get(position)) -1;
        ImageView imageView = holder.img;

        try
        {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(), mThumbIds[myNum], icon_width, icon_width));   
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            ((Index_Gridview)mContext).custom_toast("System Out-of-Error! Restarting...");
            ((Index_Gridview)mContext).restart_app();  
        }


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(myNum));       
        return convertView;
    }

private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

private int calculateInSampleSize (BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) 
    {   
        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }   
    return inSampleSize;
} 

class ViewHolder 
{
    ImageView img;
}

// References to our images in res > drawable
public Integer[] mThumbIds =  new Integer[] 
    {
        R.drawable.t_aaa, 
        R.drawable.t_bbb, 
                    ....listing of 156 image references here
    }
```

### Question:

I have already tried to import the Thumbnails via 'decodeSampledBitmapFromResource'. Original thumbnails are around 75KB each.

It will easily run into OOM. How could the codes be enhanced to alleviate the OOM error?

Thanks!!

Comment: Where did you passed `Image Height` in your `imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(), mThumbIds[myNum], icon_width, icon_width));` ?

Comment: thanks for your reply...since the thumbnails are square, i just simply use icon_width, icon_width instead

Comment: all right now plz post your `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(.....)` method.

Comment: added, thanks~~ indeed v standard decoding methods

Comment: What is the size of your each image `t_aaa,t_bbb,t_ccc,etc.......` and `resolution`?

Comment: each are around 75KB, with dimension of 400*400

Comment: you just need to recycled your all the bitmaps

Comment: could you please tell me how to?

Comment: where should i call for `myBitmap.recycle();` in the above?

Comment: Pearmak, use a view flipper with just 2 grid views in it, with two adapters. Then flip the animations round after each flip, updating a faked view pager header, so it looks like they're a view pager with 9 elements, and set state on the adapter to indicate to use the nth data set. Use a recycle listener or equivalent to call recycle() on your bitmaps, though this is no longer essential in newer versions of Android. Accordingly, you should never have more than 18 thumbnails in memory at one time. Happy to take this up in a chat if you feel like it. Best.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your brilliant idea! u mean the 2 gridview are interchanging with each other, on the 2 page of the viewpager. but i really do not know how to write for that, even after googled it...seem a big complicated...or is there any way to add recycling to the above codes?

Comment: I'd like to point out that you seem to confuse the file size of images with the amount of memory the image will take up in RAMd. The correct way to calculate image memory requirement is img_wdith * img_height * bytes_per_pixel (usually 4 in modern Android), so your 400x400 image would in fact take up 400 * 400 * 4 = 640KB, and if you times that by 156 images you'll see why you are running into OoMs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using RAM and disk cache to reuse your bitmaps.

Here's a link to the LRUCache in the android support v4:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html

and here's a link to the DiskLRUCache project by Jake Wharton

https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some memory management by yourself - no doubt about it. You can recycle offscreen pages and reload them when neccessary. LRUCache is pretty good, but it will use all your memory for images.

Your gallery is not that big and you can consider holding it in native memory. You need 30MB for hdpi 800x480 screen to 150MB for HD screen. Using JNI and C calls you can ask android for entire memory installed in the hardware (512 - 1GB). Such memory is not part of Java heap, so you don't have to worry about lack of memory for other things in your app.

Of course it's not the perfect solution, because taking more memory than your system can provide will result in allocation fail. You have to take care of it.

Link: http://code.google.com/p/native-buffer/

NativeBuffer is a kind of cache, which uses C-allocated memory to store image data. It's much faster than reloading images or caching them on sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI?tm=6 used in one example i know  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.ive it can deal with any number of images....

i think reinventing the wheel is not good and hope it helps you to acheive what you want.

thx